# How to express the comparative degree of being in the south?

Tags: phrase-request

How to express the comparative degree of being on the south?

> -- Why is it not snowing now? Isn't it winter?
>
> -- Because we are not in New-York. We are in Miami! **It's much lower down south!**

I guess "**It's much lower down south!**" is not idiomatic. So, what would be the usual way of expressing that thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the concept saying:

> Miami is ***much further south*** than New York.

Related reading:

[Southernmost Point of the Continental U.S.:](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/southernmost-point-of-the-continental-us)

> The qualifier “continental” before “U.S.A.” is required because ***Hawaii is actually farther south than Key West***. But aside from that, there are technically several islands, part of the Key West National Wildlife Refuge, ***that are farther south than the monument.*** And there are even points on the island of ***Key West proper that lie farther south than this celebrated point.***

Comment: Thank you. Would it also be okay to say "We are now much further down south"?

Comment: ...*down in the south*  would be a more common construction.

Comment: I see, thank you. But the edit you added to your question has confused me. Your main answer is "further", but in the material you've added the word  "farther" is always used. Is it because the author of that material was at the moment of writing NOT in any of those places that he was referring to, while in my example I was in Miami at the very moment of speaking? Or is it like "further" and "farther" can be used completely interchangeably?

Comment: Yes they are interchangeable here, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/farther-or-further

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is:

> We are in a **more southerly** place | clime.

[Pronunciation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/southerly):

UK  /ˈsʌð.əl.i/

US​  /ˈsʌð.ɚ.li/